# Jest testing a loop with Booleans

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following function in Jest. I have a method called isAquatic that returns a bool depending on the animal.

```
        const nonAquaticAnimal = ["tiger", "cat", "lion"]
        test.each(nonAquaticAnimal)(
          '.isAquatic',
          (input, false) => {
            const animal = isAquatic(input)
            expect(animal).toBe(false);
          },
        );
```

I have an error that says `identifier false is a reserved word and cannot be used here`. How can I loop through the array and call this method which returns a boolean?

Comment: that `false` argument is unnecessary? `(input) => {}`

Comment: You can't create an arrow function with a parameter named `false` because `false` is a reserved word.  Not sure what you originally intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array argument passed to [test.each](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) is usually a 2D array, so you can have the animal and the expected result for that animal in the `nonAquaticAnimals` array. And the test function would both the items in as function arguments.

You can have your test as follows:

```
const nonAquaticAnimals = [
  ["tiger", false],
  ["cat", false],
  ["lion", false],
];
test.each(nonAquaticAnimals)(".isAquatic", (animal, expected) => {
  expect(isAquatic(animal)).toBe(expected);
});
```

You can also omit the `expected` value from your array if you find it redundant:

```
const nonAquaticAnimals = ["tiger", "cat", "lion"];
test.each(nonAquaticAnimals)(".isAquatic", (animal) => {
  expect(isAquatic(animal)).toBe(false);
});
```